# Find the first character in a string that is a letter

Tags: c#, string, char

I am trying to figure out how to look through a string, find the first character that is a letter and then delete from that index point and on.

For example,

```
string test = "5604495Alpha";
```

I need to go through this string, find `"A"` and delete from that point on.

Comment: Old post perhaps but this is pretty simple:

int i = value.IndexOf(value.FirstOrDefault(char.IsLetter));

Need to check for -1 if no hits

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Two examples:

```
string s = "12345Alpha";
s = new string(s.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Or, more correctly, as Baldrick pointed out in his comment, find the first letter:

```
s = new string(s.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
```

Or, you can write a loop:

```
int pos = 0;
while (!Char.IsLetter(s[pos]))
{
    ++pos;
}
s = s.Substring(0, pos);
```

Comment: `TakeWhile`.. I love it. I was trying to think of a LINQ way to do it but nothing came to mind (too much F# today :/). +1

Comment: Good catch @Baldrick. Slight twist of requirements and the entire functionality shifts.

Comment: Replacing my deleted comment!: I would suggest: `s = new string(s.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());` It's supposed to be *first letter*, not *first non-digit*.

Comment: @Baldrick Perfect I was going to ask about that, this will work the best as I will have to deal with not just numbers before the first occurrence of a letter, but white spaces as well

Comment: Good catch, @Baldrick. Updated.

Comment: `s = new string(s.TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());`

Does not return anything for the above string

Comment: @JimMischel: My compiler won't let me use logical negation (!) on a method group - `TakeWhile(!Char.IsLetter)` will not compile. I think you might need the full lambda `c => !Char.IsLetter(c)`

Comment: @Baldrick: My mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @Jim `s = new string(s.TakeWhile(Char.IsNumber).ToArray());` will also do isn't it ?

Comment: @CodeGeek: Using `IsDigit` or `IsNumber` (there is a difference between those two--look it up) will give you the first non-digit. If the string contains spaces or special characters (i.e. `123^$87Alpha`), then using `IsNumber` or `IsDigit` will only return the string `123`. The OP wants up to the first letter: `123^$87`.

Answer (score 1):

A little method to do it:

```
int getIndexOfFirstLetter(string input) {
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var c in input)
        if (char.IsLetter(c))
            return index;
        else
            index++;

    return input.Length;
}
```

Usage:

```
var test = "5604495Alpha";

var result = test.Substring(0, getIndexOfFirstLetter(test));

// Returns 5604495
```

Comment: 'test = test.Split('A')[0];'

this is will why to write a method?

Comment: This short circuits `Split`s functionality. It also doesn't rely on the character `A` being the required thing to split on. It will remove _any_ character.

Comment: Ok, can you explain in detail the benefit of using the code you mentioned in broader terms.

Thanks

Comment: This will work, I was trying to expand on my question more but this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

You should break this out to make sure there is a *match*, and to make sure there is a *value* at index 0... but it does work for this example case for demonstration purposes.

```
string test = "5604495Alpha";
var test2 = test.Remove(test.IndexOf(
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(test, "[A-Za-z]").Index));
// test2 = "5604495"
```

Comment: If you're going to use a regular expression, then do `Match m = Regex.Match(test, "[A-Za-z]").Index`. Although you have to be careful here. If there is no alphabetic character, the `Index` property probably won't contain the value you want.

Comment: You could get rid of the `IndexOf` altogether: `var test2 = Regex.Match(test, "[A-Za-z]").Index);`